# Dynamically Added Nav-tabs show same content on all tabs in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mean

I have dynamically added tab in a tab pane. Whenever i click on a list item it opens a new tab with view in it but if i open say 3 tabs and navigate between the three it doesnt update the view instead shows the last opened tab View.

I want the view to be updated on select of each tab

Comment: show specific code here in which you got problem

Comment: It seems you have problem with tab.js. use ui.bootsrap tab component instead.

Comment: Plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/TxKrqnxp8PttNIcWR9BV

Comment: Exactly at Nav-tab chnage i want to capture that n show that tabs content